# How to use proximity sensors on a mobile device to enable 2 android devices to communicate?

Tags: android, android-sensors, proximity

I am a student studying software development currently, and we were asked to come up with a project of our choice to work on for the next few months.

I want to create an android application as this is where my interests lays.

Now, the idea i have is not fully developed yet but hopefully you guys can help.  The idea is:

If i create an app, and this app is enabled/installed on 2 android devices, as long as this 2 devices are in range of a certain distance I would set, they can communicate.

It could turn out to be a messaging system, or image sharing etc.  But my question is, is it possible to use proximity to enable 2 android devices with the app installed to communicate?

Keep in mind, I am no expert in Android but I am no beginner either.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The simplest way to do it would most likely be to use the GPS in both of the phones to work out the distance between them. You could also use Bluetooth between the two devices, as this is short range.

Comment: Yeah even that would be perfectly fine.  I just need something that would tell both devices "Hey, you got another device close to you that has the same app as you"! I will go and take a look into this.  Thanks a lot,mate.

Comment: You'd probably need to have people opening the application itself if you were to use Bluetooth, as I don't think making devices discoverable is a great idea when they're not in use. The GPS option may be the best option here; have a central server and send the phone's positions to it, the server compares the distances and alerts both of the phones if they are nearby.

Comment: Yeah the GPS method defiantly sounds like a solution.  Now excuse my noob'ness but could you elaborate on the central server?  Keep in mind, I am a student and most likely cannot get my hands on a server.

Comment: By "central server" I just mean an application running on a computer that can be accessed by the devices. If the application is for an assignment (i.e. a temporary solution), you could run the application on a local network and ensure both devices are on the same network. They can then send messages to/from the server (i.e. the application), as they're on the same network. If it's a more permanent solution, you'll need to run it on something like a VPS where it can be accessed from anywhere and is up 24/7. You could use something as simple as PHP with a web server as your server.

Comment: Yup! I totally understand! I will surely look into this and see if I decide to stick to the idea.  I really appreciate the help,matey! All the best!

Comment: You too! I hope your project turns out well :)